Zustand updating in one place but not another
I am building an application that allows users to create posts using React and Zustand. Inside this hook useGetUserPosts, I am trying to get data from my Firebase database and set "posts" equal to the data in the querySnapshot. However, it seems the setPosts function is not working properly; it is only in one place. Initially inside getPosts, I set posts to an empty array, and that worked, but then in the try block, I tried to set it equal to the data, but it doesn't update the state here.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import usePostStore from '../store/postStore'
import useDisplayToast from './useDisplayToast'
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, getDocsFromCache } from "firebase/firestore";
import { firestore } from '../firebase/firebase';
import useUserProfileStore from '../store/ProfileStore';

const useGetUserPosts = () => {

    const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false)
    const userProfile = useUserProfileStore(state => state.userProfile)
    const posts = usePostStore(state => state.posts)
    const setPosts = usePostStore(state => state.setPosts)
    const toast = useDisplayToast()
    const getPosts = async() => {

        if(!userProfile) return

        setIsFetching(true)
        setPosts([])
        console.log(userProfile)

        try{

            const q = query(collection(firestore, "posts"), where("createdBy", "==", userProfile.uid));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)

            let docs = []

            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => docs.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
            console.log(docs)
            setPosts(docs)
            console.log(posts)


        } catch(error) {
            toast("Error", error.message, "error")
            setPosts([])

        } finally {
            setIsFetching(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getPosts()

    }, [userProfile, setPosts])

    return {isFetching, posts}
}

export default useGetUserPosts


I logged userProfile and the data docs and I confirm the retrieving data part is correct. There I see an array with 6 items in it as expected. It's only after the *setPosts(docs) * I logged posts and I get an empty array.
For testing purposes, I have also tried to set posts equal to different values in both places. I ended up getting whatever I set before the try block. It's as if nothing happens when I call setPosts in the try block.
Here's my Zustand store just for your reference. I doubt it's the problem though, given the first setPosts worked perfectly.
import {create} from 'zustand'

const usePostStore = create((set) => ({
    posts: [],
    createPost: (post) => set(state => ({posts: [post, ...state.posts]})),
    setPosts: (posts) => set({posts})
}))
    


export default usePostStore

